Modular Arithmetic on Public Key
How can I multiply my secp256k1 elliptic curve public key by half the order of the curve modulo half the order of the curve? For instance, my public key is obtained by multiplying the generator point by my private key, $11$. Let half the order of the curve on the secp256k1 elliptic curve be:
$$h = \small{57896044618658097711785492504343953926418782139537452191302581570759080747169}$$
I am trying to multiply my public key by $h$ modulo $h$. I attempted the operation:
$$\text{pubkey} \cdot h \mod h$$
but both tinyec and fastecdsa return errors indicating that I cannot perform a modulo operation between a point and an integer.
Additionally, ChatGPT has suggested that it is not possible to perform a modulo operation on a point like a public key. However, I believe otherwise due to the cyclic nature of the elliptic curve.

The order $n$ of secp256k1 is a large prime, thus odd, thus "half the order of the curve" is not an integer. The stated $h$ is actually $(n+1)/2$. The fragment "multiply my public key by $h$" makes sense, is easy, and performs so-called point halving (that is, inverts point doubling). But "multiply my public key by $h$ modulo $h$" makes little sense. What are you really trying to achieve with the " modulo $h$" part of the question ? Or should we read "modulo the order of the curve" (that is $n=2h-1$)? Please edit to clarify.

What problem are you actually trying to solve?  I suspect it's something that, if we could actually do it, we could solve discrete logs efficiently (hence, the security of secp256k1 would go away)

I am sure I have seen versions of this question by (possibly) other posters as well, specifically the "half the order of the curve" part.

@kodlu: With this specific wording "half the order of the curve", Google finds nothing else on crypto-SE. But it does find this, which attempts to reverse double-and-add by identifying if a point was obtained by add or by double. And yes we had more than our share of this. Which can't work, because the two are possible and equally likely.
